# Lewis Acid Catalysts

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, synthesis, catalysis

I am studying for the International Chemistry Olympiad and some of questions involve synthesis of complicated organic compounds and i have no idea how to do them.

The setting of the questions is usually like this: they give you a rough idea of the end product however some of the groups are replaced with R. They replace all the other intermediates with A, B, C ... They also give the reactants and catalysts for each step.

Most of the time the catalysts are lewis acids. I wondering if you were able to provide mechanisms and general resulting reactions of these catalyses so i could predict what the product will be.

Also, is $\ce{NaBH4}$ a lewis acid?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! I am afraid, I do not quite understand what you are asking. I might be better, if you could provide us with a specific question, an example of what you are struggling with. In its current form, this question might be too broad and is likely to be closed. You also might want to consider to ask two separate questions for the two problems you face.

Comment: Ask yourself: can NaBH4 accept anymore electrons? Remember the octet rule.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of a question, so we know the exact context?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reading my question and sorry for being really confusing. I cant write the question down as it is really long and i cant draw the structures here. Here is the link to the question- file:///C:/Users/pc/Downloads/volume3-icho41-45.pdf

Comment: It is the 7th question from the 2011 paper on page 1272.

Comment: @the The "link" you posted is a pathname on your computer. It will not help us and we cannot help you.

Comment: @bon The edit you suggested was not really necessary, I approved it, but generally I would consider this to be too minor.

Comment: Sorry, i am not the best when it comes to computers. However it doesn't really matter, all i want to know is general mechanisms for reactions involving lewis acid catalysts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $\ce{NaBH4}$ is not a Lewis acid because it cannot accept any more electrons. Aqueous $\ce{NaBH4}$ is a commonly used reducing agent often for reduction of carbonyls to their respective alcohols.

The mechanism of Lewis acid catalysis depends on the reaction but often Lewis acids are used to generate cationic electrophiles such as in the Friedel-Crafts reaction. [image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my  question. However is there any other reaction mechanisms involving lewis acid catalysts?

Comment: @the any reaction where you want a cationic electrophile could quite easily involve a lewis acid. are you thinking of any specific example?